# sequential setState calls very close in time only provoke one render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating a translation animation for an element with this simple css

```
.translated {
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform: translate(100px);
}
```

translated class is applied to the element according to the `translated` field in the state.

So I trigger an animation by calling animate :

```
animate = () => {
    this.setState({translated: false}, // reset element position
     () => this.setState({translated: true}) // translate element with animation
    )
}
```

the problem is that my component only renders after the second `stateState` call because they ocure to close together in time.

How can I have both `setState` call render ?

**Update :**

Puting the second setState in a setInterval callback makes the animation work:

```
animate = () => {
      this.setState({translated: false}); // reset element position
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({translated: true})) // translate element with animation
    ) 

}
```

I still don't understand where the issue is coming from.
I should be getting the same result when putting the second setState in the callback of the first setState !

Comment: why are you calling this.setState with two parameters? AFAIK you need only one parameter... the new partial state object or a function.

Comment: do you to wait until the second `setState` called ?

Comment: @Ali. I don't understand. Second setState should be called after the second one is completed

Comment: in your example `translated` will be false and after that it will be true but this will be fast

Comment: @Lev FYI: passing `setTimeout()` call as the second parameter doesn't make sense, since that means you are passing timeout ID instead of callback. If you place your `setTimeout()` call on the next line after  `this.setState({translated: false});` you'll get the same result

Comment: You are right. Still I don't know how come it works that way. The initial example with the second setState after the first one should work !

Comment: @Lev I've updated my answer with explanation

Answer (score 3):

`setState()` calls are optimised internally by React. From the docs:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

So what you want is to call the second `setState()` from inside the callback of the first one, so you can be sure first update is already done:

```
animate = () => {
    this.setState({translated: false}, () => {
        this.setState({translated: true});
    });
}
```

You can see it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/xtnrcLdh/1/

**Update:**

I focused on how React acts internally though there is nothing to do with React here. The issue here is that browser is not triggering reflow between two render calls, so your element always has its `translated` class on it at the time of reflow.

More information on this issue: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/, https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

What finally should work for your case is either using `setTimeout()` or to force reflow by accessing `window.scrollX` property for example:

```
animate = () => {
    this.setState({translated: false}, () => {
        window.scrollX;
        this.setState({translated: true});
    });
}
```

Comment: it is what I'm doing. It doesn't render on both setState calls

Comment: @Lev notice that I am using callback form `() => { this.setState(...) }` in my example. You just passed `this.setState(...)` as a parameter

Comment: @akm sorry I updated my example. Unfortunately it doesn't update twice.

Comment: @Lev I am pretty sure it should call render twice, can you put `console.log()` outputs to check that? Maybe issue is related to CSS. I've added jsfiddle demonstrating how it works

Comment: The render should happen, then the state should update. You can use rAF for that. `this.setState({ translated: false }, () => {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.setState({ translated: true }));
          });`

Comment: @Kunukn. The only solution that works is wrapping the second setState in a setTimeout callback. I don't understand why though..